# nav bar is shown above image which is absolute unable to break absolute html css

Tags: html, css

Am trying to keep a navbar below the div which has position relative and absolute conditions but when am trying to keep the nav bar below the image3.png its coming above image3.png below the jobs heading how can I make the nav come as usual below the image. Here is screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqLI1.jpg

Here is my code

```
 .clsFirstImg {
               position: relative;
               top: 0;
               left: 0;
               margin:0 auto;
               z-index: 10;
           }
         .clsSecondImg {
               width:15%;
               position: absolute;
               top: 10%;
               left: 40%;
               z-index:100
            }
         .clsThirdImg {
               width:85.4%;
               position: absolute;
               top: 23.5%;
                 left:7.3%
                }
           .heading
            {
               position: absolute;
               top: 30%;
               left:40%;
               z-index:200;
             }


<div>

 <img src="image1.png" class="img-responsive clsFirstImg">
    <a href="#"><img src="image2.png" class="img-responsive clsSecondImg"></a>
      <a href="#" style="color:white"><h1 class="heading">jobs</h1></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="image3.png" class="img-responsive clsThirdImg"></a>

 </div>


<center>

<!---navbar start--->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
     <div class="container">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
           </ul>
       </div>
    </nav>

  <!---navbar end--->
  </center>
```

Comment: Could you make code snippet so we can see what's happening? you can make them by CTRL+M

Comment: @NoOorZ24 its showing like this in fiddle its working correct only http://imgur.com/a/nNbCZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I can do, Remember one thing this is static, If you want this responsive then You have to use container>row>col- , I think you know it..

```css
*{
 margin: 0 auto;
}
body{
 background: url(bg.jpg);
}
.clsFirstImg{
position: relative;
z-index: 111;
}
.clsSecondImg{
position: relative;
margin-top: -180px;
z-index: 222;
}
.clsThirdImg{
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <img src="images1.png" class="img-responsive clsFirstImg">
  <a href="#"><img src="images2.png" class="img-responsive clsSecondImg"></a>
  <img src="images3.png" class="img-responsive clsThirdImg">

</div>


<center>
  <!---navbar start--->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!---navbar end--->
</center>
```

Comment: when am using that the third image is coming below the first image I want third image to be behind of the first image

Comment: Actually this process is wrong.. You need to set third image first. Then next two images positioned relative to parent image(3rd image).

Comment: if the third image is relative then next two images are absolute

Comment: Yes, Post a pic what you exactly want.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/hVEol in this link first one is expected but am getting second one

Comment: Please upload those 3 pics.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/nOQtH here are images am trying to make it responsive also but unable to

Comment: can you remove images please

Answer (score 0):

Probably we cannot do with absolute position. But i added some code relevant to your needs. Kindly check.

```css
.top{background:#ff0000;width:100%;padding-bottom:70%;}
 .clsFirstImg {
               width:20%;
               top: 0;
               left: 0;
               margin:0 auto;
               z-index: 10;
           }
         .clsSecondImg {
               width:25%;
               position:absolute;
               top: 10%;
               left: 40%;
               z-index:100;
              
            }
         .clsThirdImg {
               width:85.4%;
               position:absolute;
               top: 23.5%;
                left:7.3%
                }
           .heading
            {
               position:absolute;
               top: 30%;
               left:40%;
               z-index:200;
             }


center{background-color:#ff00ff;}
```

```html
<div class="top">

    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS-EjO7WIBpny2Q9beiqP45EfiOGLXYxTDLtaDWhf4LQ43Y36Xtv0iMEkN4" class="img-responsive clsFirstImg"/>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS-EjO7WIBpny2Q9beiqP45EfiOGLXYxTDLtaDWhf4LQ43Y36Xtv0iMEkN4" class="img-responsive clsSecondImg"></a>
    <a href="#" style="color:white"><h1 class="heading">jobs</h1></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS-EjO7WIBpny2Q9beiqP45EfiOGLXYxTDLtaDWhf4LQ43Y36Xtv0iMEkN4" class="img-responsive clsThirdImg"></a>

 </div>


<center>

<!---navbar start--->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
     <div class="container">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
           </ul>
       </div>
    </nav>

  <!---navbar end--->
  </center>
```